# Conversão String para Float

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, float, graphics

Estou tentando plotar um gráfico, mas estou tendo o seguinte retorno "could not convert string to float" na última linha desse trecho do código. Alguém tem ideia do que consigo fazer?

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
igs = 50*'='
desenho = plot.figure()
papel = desenho.add_subplot(111)
desenho.patch.set_color('white')

print('Grafico de f : [a,b] -> R/n', igs)
print('Intervalo a,b:')
a,b =np.float64(input('a,b ='))
```

Comment: Qual a entrada passada em `input('a,b =')` ? As linhas `from __future__ import unicode_literals`  e `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, de  `igs = 50*'='` até `print('Intervalo a,b:')` parecem não ter relevância alguma para a questão, as únicas linhas que importam são `import numpy as np` e `a,b =np.float64(input('a,b ='))`, a mensagem de erro na integra e uma amostra da entrada.

Answer (score 1):

O input recebe valores no formato string. Sendo assim, é necessário usar o `split()`.

```
a, b = np.float64(input('a,b =').split(","))
```

Exemplo

```
In [5]: a,b =np.float64(input('a,b =').split(","))
a,b =12.34,98.76

In [6]: a
Out[6]: 12.34

In [7]: b
Out[7]: 98.76
```